# Inkscape calligraphy tool producing odd stroke inversions near sharp curves

Tags: inkscape

Strange things are happening in the sharper bends of lines drawn with the calligraphy tool (see the locations indicated by the arrows).  I don't use this tool that often, but I have work from a few years ago that doesn't have this problem.  I've been fiddling with the settings for hours and can not figure out how to prevent this.  Any suggestions?

- Inkscape version: Inkscape 1.3.2 (1:1.3.2+202311252150+091e20ef0f)
- Stylus: Wacom Bamboo Pen model CTL-470

[image]

Comment: Hi. I'm having difficulty reproducing this. Although from time to time the calligraphy tool can glitch a bit, I can't really get anything that resembles your screenshot.  What version of Inkscape are you using?  Sometimes, a sudden jerky pen/mouse movement can cause more glitches, so I like to increase the mass to around 10 for calligraphy work. It can help smooth things out a bit.  Also try increasing the fixation to 100.  Can you try that and see if it improves things?  If not, you may want to report this as a bug.

Comment: Another thing I notice is that you have the Tilt button enabled, but as far as I know, Wacom Bamboos don't have tilt sensitivity. Try removing that, and use a fixed angle instead.